# convert sql from server syntax to absolute database

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, unidac

This is the original code that worked with SQL Server using Unidac components :
In the SQL (TStrings) of the uniQuery I had :

```
 use HIS
    DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
            @EndDate    DATETIME,
            @RoomType   VARCHAR(6)
    ;

     SELECT @StartDate  = '2011-04-15',
            @EndDate    = '2011-04-26',
            @RoomType   = 'DBLMS'
    ;
    WITH 
    cteStayDates AS
    ( 
     SELECT RoomType  = Room_Type,
            StartDate = CASE WHEN Rate_Start_Date < @StartDate THEN @StartDate ELSE Rate_Start_Date END,
            EndDate   = CASE WHEN Rate_End_Date   > @EndDate   THEN @EndDate   ELSE Rate_End_Date   END,
            Rate
       FROM dbo.Room_Rates
      WHERE @RoomType  = Room_Type
        AND @StartDate < Rate_End_Date
        AND @EndDate  >= Rate_Start_Date
    ) 
     SELECT RoomType, StartDate, EndDate, Rate, 
            Days = DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate)
                 + CASE WHEN EndDate = @EndDate THEN 0 ELSE 0 END
       FROM cteStayDates
      ORDER BY StartDate
    ;
```

On Button click I had :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
//uniQuery1.SQL.Add('SET DATEFORMAT DMY');
begin
uniQuery1.Close;
uniQuery1.SQL.Clear;
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('@EndDate    DATETIME,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('@RoomType   VARCHAR(6);');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT @StartDate  = :a2,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('@EndDate    = :a3,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('@RoomType   = :a1;');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('WITH');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('cteStayDates AS');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('( SELECT RoomType  = Room_Type,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('StartDate = CASE WHEN Rate_Start_Date < @StartDate THEN @StartDate ELSE Rate_Start_Date END,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('EndDate   = CASE WHEN Rate_End_Date   > @EndDate   THEN @EndDate   ELSE Rate_End_Date   END,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('Rate');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('FROM dbo.Room_Rates');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE @RoomType  = Room_Type');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('AND @StartDate < Rate_End_Date');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('AND @EndDate  >= Rate_Start_Date)');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT RoomType, StartDate, EndDate, Rate,');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('Days = DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate)');
//uniQuery1.SQL.Add('+ CASE WHEN EndDate = @EndDate THEN 0 ELSE 0 END');
uniQuery1.SQL.Add('FROM cteStayDates  ORDER BY StartDate;');
uniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('a1').AsString := cxTextEdit1.Text;
uniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('a3').AsDate := cxDateEdit2.Date; // end date
uniQuery1.Params.ParamByName('a2').AsDate := cxDateEdit1.Date; // start date
uniQuery1.Open;


end;
```

Now I am trying to port this code to absolute database (table fields are the same) but can not get it to work. Can someone help me with this ?

I also tried putting this query in the SQL text of the ABSQuery1:

```
SELECT RoomType, StartDate, EndDate, Rate, 
            Days = DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate)
                 + CASE WHEN EndDate = EndDate THEN 0 ELSE 0 END
  RoomType  = Room_Type,
            StartDate = CASE WHEN Rate_Start_Date < StartDate THEN StartDate ELSE Rate_Start_Date END,
            EndDate   = CASE WHEN Rate_End_Date   > EndDate   THEN EndDate   ELSE Rate_End_Date   END,
            Rate
       FROM Room_Rates
      WHERE RoomType  = Room_Type
        AND StartDate < Rate_End_Date
        AND EndDate  >= Rate_Start_Date      ORDER BY StartDate
    ;
```

But I can not retrieve fields so it does not wok. Really dont know why. Connection is set up properly. When I try and retrieve the fields I get :
[image]

Comment: Presumably it creates some kind of error. What is that error? A guess would be that it has issues with the CTE and/or DATEDIFF. The CTE can be rewritten as a sub-query and if DATEIFF is the issue you have to check the documentation for Absolute database to see what you can do instead.

Comment: Absolute Database does not support `Common Table Expressions` (`CTEs`). For the appropriate syntax to use, see the Absolute documentation.

Comment: Documentation is pro oriented, not suitable for beginners.

Comment: You could remove the `datediff` and do the calculation on the client instead. Also your first `CASE` does not seem to ad much value here.

Comment: how would you write it ?

Comment: Did your query work if you remove `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: I think I must rewrite this query from scratch .... Perhaps one option is to add a calculated field to the query representing stay_dates ...

Comment: @user763539 Pro oriented? That's like saying the dictionary is only for people that can read.

Comment: easy for you to say.... I learn by real world examples :)

Comment: Yes I think you are correct. You should rewrite the query starting with something that works and add new features untill you find what parts does not work in Absolute database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common Table Expressions (`with cteStayDates as (..)`) are a SQL Server feature that are probably not in absolute. You could try something like:

```
 use HIS
    DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
            @EndDate    DATETIME,
            @RoomType   VARCHAR(6)
    ;

     SELECT @StartDate  = '2011-04-15',
            @EndDate    = '2011-04-26',
            @RoomType   = 'DBLMS'
    ;
     SELECT RoomType, StartDate, EndDate, Rate, 
            Days = DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate)
                 + CASE WHEN EndDate = @EndDate THEN 0 ELSE 0 END
  RoomType  = Room_Type,
            StartDate = CASE WHEN Rate_Start_Date < @StartDate THEN @StartDate ELSE Rate_Start_Date END,
            EndDate   = CASE WHEN Rate_End_Date   > @EndDate   THEN @EndDate   ELSE Rate_End_Date   END,
            Rate
       FROM dbo.Room_Rates
      WHERE @RoomType  = Room_Type
        AND @StartDate < Rate_End_Date
        AND @EndDate  >= Rate_Start_Date      ORDER BY StartDate
    ;
```

Comment: Absolute database it seems does not support: USE or DECLARE.